# Ubuntu on USB doesn't recognize TB size on HD for install

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, storage

I am trying to load Ubuntu desktop ISO that was put on a USB stick, into new PC build. When the process starts, an error

> Ubuntu requires 8.6 GB, and only 8GB available

comes up. I have an 8TB external HD attached.

The tech person at Micro Center (where I bought all the parts) said that Ubuntu doesn't understand "TB" due to the extra zero, and I need to download something different for my USB before installing it into a new PC? Cannot find anything about this in the FAQ.

Note there is nothing (i.e. Windows) currently on PC.  It's a brand new build.

Comment: Thanks ExisDeni.  I just went to make sure, and now have new confusion.  When I turn on the PC with the USB inserted, I get the first option to "try or install Ubuntu" I choose install, then I get a "keyboard layout" option with languages, and choose that, then it goes right to the error that I "don't have enough storage space" and my only option is to go back or quit.  I don't see how to tell if it's connected to my external 8TB HD or not.  What gets really weird is that when I "quit" it looks like I'm on my new Ubuntu desktop like it was partially installed?

Comment: Please boot into a live session (Try Ubuntu without installing), download GParted, and run it, take a screenshot and post it into your question above.

Comment: Now I can't even do that.  The "Ubuntu" desktop is up on my screen, looking like it installed just fine. Even when I pull the USB out.  There is still an "Install Ubuntu" shortcut on the desktop, and when I double-click, it skips right to the "language" then the "error." I don't get an option to "try without downloading." I'm trying to figure out how to even find my 8TB HD in Ubuntu.  I clicked on "disks" and it's not popping up?  Only the USB until I pulled it out.

Comment: I can open "GParted" in Applications, but it says "No Devices detected" unless I put the USB back in and refresh

Comment: I built my own machine (the one I am using right now) and it wasn't without hiccups. Can you get a screenshot of GParted? What hard drive did you install? Could it be a faulty connection? BTW I don't suggest to pull out the live USB drive while it is running.

Comment: Oh you wanna talk about hiccups? I just figured out my problem.  Turns out my sweet 8TB Internal HD also requires its own Power Supply cable.  Maybe I should fully read instructions before getting so damn excited.......

Comment: Hang in there, once you get to know Linux, you will be sold on it! Post it as your answer and I will give it a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are selecting the correct device (hard drive) to install on?
You can check Disks or GParted to get your device name.